Are these two definitions of dense partial order equivalent?
Let $(P,\leq)$ be a partial order. One definition of density is that if $x$ and $y$ are in $P$ and $x$ is strictly less than $y$, then there is a $z \in P$ such that $x<z<y$. The other definition is that if $x \neq y$, then there is a $z \in P$ such that $z$ is strictly between $x$ and $y$, where by strict betweenness I mean the ternary relation $B(x,z,y)$ that holds if and only if $x<z<y \vee y<z<x$. I believe these two definitions are equivalent in case $\leq$ is a linear order, but what about for general partial orders? Also, bonus question, is there an example of a non-linear partial order where the second definition holds? Or must all partial orders that satisfy the second definition be linear?

The second is only useful if $P$ is a total order, not a general partial order, because it means if $x\neq y,$ either $x<y$ or $y<x.$

The second definition implies (via transitivity) that any two distinct elements are comparable. Thus, it indeed forces a partial order to be linear.
The correct definition of density for partial orders is indeed the first one.
